# How to show value in only first cell in case of duplicate Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I wrote a query in Power BI which returns results like this

[image]

Is it possible: For the first column Service Name if value is same in cells than to show value in the first cell and than leaves all the other cells blank until the value is changed, If the new value is repeating than again leave all the cells blank until a new value found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to change the table visualization to matrix visualization.

Just keep the column under the `Rows` section.

[image: rows]

The matrix visualization will then group and hide the repeating values automatically.

[image: result]

Comment: ahhh it's that simple

Answer (score 2):

For me, when I switched to a Matrix visualization, it displayed all fields in a single column with plus signs to view detail.  To show each field in a separate column, go to "Column Headers" and turn off "Stepped layout".

Answer (score 0):

Use Matrix visualization
Add Service Name and Ticket Type into the Rows
Drill down the visule
go to setting, and under Row Header, remove Stepped